# Q:Multiple root bones after exporting to UE4

Tags: armature, export

I have seen similar questions before but couldn't find an answer. When I try to import my animated mesh to UE4 it gives an error saying there are multiple roots in the armature. I did export other animated meshes from blender to unreal and didn't have this problem.

Comment: This is a thread from UE4 answer hub: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/109814/multiple-roots-are-found-in-the-bone-hierarchy-we.html

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me` I selected model, bones and create a copy, then I exported a copy of model and this issue was fixed.